# How to use angular-ui/ui-calendar (arshaw/fullcalendar) loading call back?

Tags: angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I'm trying to implement the loading callback function using the angular-ui calendar. I want my calendar to go to a specific date once it is loaded instead of going to the current date.

I can get this functionality using the dayClick method, however I have not been able to implement the loading function using angular at all. Below is the code, note that the loading callback is not console logging anything.

```
 $scope.goToRootScopeDate = function() {
     $scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $rootScope.day);
  }

    /* config calendar view  */
  $scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
      defaultView: "agendaDay",
      // editable: true,
      header: {
        left: 'agendaWeek',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today prev,next',
      },
      dayClick: $scope.goToRootScopeDate,
      loading: function(bool) {
        if (bool) {
          console.log('Done loading')
        } else {
          console.log("still loading")
        }
      }
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you want to manage the Loading callback method from the ng-controller...**

[Loading callback](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/loading/) receives two parameters, not a boolean.

```
  /* config calendar view  */
  $scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
      defaultView: "agendaDay",
      // editable: true,
      header: {
        left: 'agendaWeek',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today prev,next',
      },
      dayClick: $scope.goToRootScopeDate,
      loading: $scope.loading

    },
  };
```

And then you manage it in the controller with those 2 parameters

```
$scope.loading = function(isLoading, view){
      alert("is loading" + isLoading);
    }
```

You can reproduce it at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HyNUq2?p=preview) where I added some annoying alerts to manage the loading callback.

**But, if you only want to load a specific date at the first screen...**
Just set the [defaultdate](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/) in the config:

```
/* config calendar view  */
      $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
          defaultView: "agendaDay",
          // editable: true,
          header: {
            left: 'agendaWeek',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'today prev,next',
          },
          dayClick: $scope.goToRootScopeDate,
          defaultDate:$scope.myDesiredDate

        },
      };
```

Comment: Really appreciate the formatting.  helped me organize my directive.